# NSString method to percent escape '&' for URL

Tags: cocoa-touch, encoding, nsstring

Which NSString encoding method will percent escape the ampersand (**&**) character correctly into `%26`?

```
stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
```

gets the spaces (%20) and other baddies but ignores ampersands!?!

Comment: Ampersand is a valid character in URLs. `www.example.com?a=5&b=7`

Comment: i know..but it's messing up my query parameters so need to "remove" occurrences of & in values before adding to query string..

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Ampersands won't be processed by that method because they're legal characters in a URL. You should probably pre-process particularly problematic pieces, piecemeal, prior to this call.

Answer (score 23):

Here is a nice solution to this problem taken from [Bagonca blog](http://www.bagonca.com/blog/2009/04/08/iphone-tip-1-url-encoding-in-objective-c/) to url-encode your NSStrings :

```
+ (NSString *)urlEncodeValue:(NSString *)str
{
   NSString *result = (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)str, NULL, CFSTR(":/?#[]@!$&’()*+,;="), kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
   return [result autorelease];
}
```

Add `CFBridgingRelease(` for ARC compatibility.

```
+ (NSString *)urlEncodeValue:(NSString *)str
{
    NSString *result = (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)str, NULL, CFSTR(":/?#[]@!$&’()*+,;="), kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
    return result;
}
```

Comment: This resolved my issue. The answer was difficult to find because I didn't know that the cause was characters in my POST body. It seemed like it was due to the size of my file. If you are sending a sendAsynchronousRequest and the request terminates the payload, check for the encoding. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

The accepted answer isn't quite right I don't think, you need to process the string **after** calling addPercentEscapesAndReplaceAmpersand

```
+ (NSString *) addPercentEscapesAndReplaceAmpersand: (NSString *) stringToEncode
{
    NSString *encodedString = [stringToEncode stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
    return [encodedString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"&" withString: @"%26"];
}
```

Comment: yeah but that would wreck the alliteration!

Comment: That isn't right either if you build a query string like ?foo=bar&bar=foo and then replace all the &s with %26, it's not a valid query string any more.

Comment: You would want to process the bar and foo values rather than the whole query string.