# password with percentage symbol always wrong iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, authentication

I'm developing an iPhone application in Xcode with a login function and I'm having trouble with the following code:

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",username],password];
NSLog(post);

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",username] forHTTPHeaderField:@"username"];
[request addValue:password forHTTPHeaderField:@"password"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
action = @"token";
NSURLConnection *connection;
connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Now there is a member with the password %32dzs3* and the app always gives an error that the password is incorrect. When I NSLog the password it's indeed not the password I typed in the textfield. it looked like this: 50883393zs3* . I also tried this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < [password length];i++){
    if([password characterAtIndex:i] == '%'){
        NSString *temporarypw = [password substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, i)];
        password = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%%%%%@",temporarypw,[password substringWithRange:NSMakeRange((i+1), (password.length - i -1))]];
        break;
    }
}
```

this returns the password as %%%%32dzs3* and the password is right when I NSLog it. still the response is a wrong password response when I run the request. How can I fix this?

Comment: You mean in your application, the password is sent in clear text and not escaped? Ouch. I don't want to be one of your users.

Answer (score 2):

`%` is a special character in HTTP URLs.  You need to [escape it before creating the URL](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000301-BAJBBDIB), also `:`, `/`, `#`, `;`, and `@`.  Fortunately `NSString` has a [method](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding%3a) to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to escape the password correctly. See this question:
[NSString method to percent escape '&' for URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159341/nsstring-method-to-percent-escape-for-url)