# NSURL - Correct Encoding for parameters

Tags: ios, iphone, nsurl, nsstringencoding

In my code I need to do encoding `NSURL` from `NSString` if string contains some special character `&` in the parameters.

EX: `NSString* urlText = @"70.84.58.40/projects/igolf/?TipThumb=GOLF & 58B.jpg&query=some";`

Using `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding`will not encode `&` and this would be treated as some other query in url.
So, What would be correct format for encoding `NSURL` from `NSString`in this case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/705448/iphone-sdk-issue-with-ampersand-in-the-url-string and/or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159341/nsstring-method-to-percent-escape-for-url

Answer (score 0):

You can use this static helper method to encode your strings for a URL:

```
+ (NSString*)urlEncode:(NSString*)encodingString
{
    return (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,
       (CFStringRef)encodingString,
       NULL,
       (CFStringRef)@" ",
       CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create the Category on NSString to bypass the problem, try this [link](http://madebymany.com/blog/url-encoding-an-nsstring-on-ios) where solution is provided. Here is the sample code from the post

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface NSString (URLEncoding)
-(NSString *)urlEncodeUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding;
@end
```

And here’s the implementation:

```
#import "NSString+URLEncoding.h"
@implementation NSString (URLEncoding)
-(NSString *)urlEncodeUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding {
    return (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,
               (CFStringRef)self,
               NULL,
               (CFStringRef)@"!*'\"();:@&=+$,/?%#[]% ",
               CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(encoding));
}
@end
```

And now we can simply do this:

```
NSString *raw = @"GOLF & 58B.jpg&query=some";
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"70.84.58.40/projects/igolf/?TipThumb=%@",
            [raw urlEncodeUsingEncoding:NSUTF8Encoding]];
```