# Can't do google search with "&" character on WKWebView

Tags: ios, webkit, google-search, wkwebview

I have a `WKWebView` in my app that allows a user to search on Google.

Everything works fine but searches with "&" character. For instance, if I search for *at&t*, I will have the results of the search of *at*.

If I print the url of my web view in `didCommitNavigation`, I can see the right searched terms *at&t*

```
func webView(webView: WKWebView, didCommitNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!)
{
        print(webView.URL?.absoluteString)
}
```

returns

> https://www.google.fr/search?hl=en&q=at&t=&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=8f-hV4iJGM-ba6qvh-gJ

We can see the q parameter : `q=at&t` whereas the result page is the same as the one for `q=at`.

Any ideas to solve that problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2159350/710041) verifies, the & is not automatically escaped in the usual way, so you probably have to process your search string manually (wherever your user enters the terms, just replace the & when you get it from there):

```
let searchterm = getTermFromWherever()
let actualterm = searchterm.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("&", withString: "%26")
```

This should work.